# how to solve undefined references in a complex project?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, linker

I have a complex project, which consists of source files in various sub-directories which are compiled  and archived into libXXX.a files.
This compiled and linked well.

I now added the new file `stdstrutils.cpp` (together with its header file `stdstrutils.h`) to the sub-project in the "common" subdirectory.

This file contains a function with an ordinary template,

`template<typename T> bool strToNum(const std::string sData, T *t);`

and one with a variadic template,

`template<typename... Args> std::string stdsprintf(const std::string sForma, Args... args);`

(the declarations in the header file exactly match the functions in the c++-file)
These functions are used by four c++-files in various of the sub-directories.

I added the line `#include "stdstrutils.cpp"` to the #includes in all the files that use the templated functions from `stdstrutils`, but i still get a lot of  'undefined reference to'-message from the linker. All concern the template-functions from `stdstrutils`.

The code of `stdstrutils` is definitely linked into the library `libCommon.a`: i checked this with a test-program - it compiled and linked without complaints, and executed as expected.

This is the link command from the make file:

```
 ~/utils/cgcc -fopenmp -std=c++11 -Wall -g  -o QHGMain \
  QHGMain.o Simulator.o SimParams.o EventChecker.o GridScrambler.o \
  -L ../populations -lPopulations \
  -L ../genes -lGenes \
  -L ../kernel -lKernel \
  -L ../modular -lModular \
  -L ../qmaps -lQMap \
  -L ../icosa -lIcosa \
  -L ../geoinfo -lGeoInfo \
  -L ../common -lCommon \
  -L ../io -lIO \
    -lz -lhdf5 -lm -lcrypto
```

The callers of the functions from `stdstrutils` are in `libCommon`, `libKernel` as well as in the main directory (`EventChecker.o`).

Confusingly, there are other functions in `libCommon` which also have templates (and are called from different files), but they cause none of the 'undefined reference to'-messages.

So is there some rule about where to include the cpp-files (with the templated functions) which helps me avoid these messages?

Comment: Template functions are typically implemented in header files (for this very reason). Or in a separate file, which is included at the end of header file.

Comment: Related if not a duplicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: *"in a complex project?"* understand the issue with a smaller project.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen; This does not seem to be necessary. I have template functions in similarly split h and cpp files, which do not cause this error. I have now #included stdstrutils.cpp at the end of stdstrutils.h, but it still reports undefined references.

Comment: @Jarod: i tried to build simpler projects, but so far none of them show the errors.

Comment: I had this kind of issues with template functions or template classes. I could split it in .h and .cpp files only when I had a friend function with this function being put in the cpp file. I recommend to copy the implementation of your function into your header file and include the header file rather than the cpp file (which is always a bit awkward and uncommon),

Comment: There's nothing in standard about dividing code into header files and .cpp files, every compiler will happily accept any file with valid code. That distinction is something created purely for humans, and purely for one goal - to let them easily separate things that must only have one copy in the program from things that may have multiple copies. If you destroy that convention and start including .cpp files, it *will* create problems in the future, when somebody else (or even you) will need to change that code and they will not know/remember about that convention break.